# How to compile latex equations in markdown with Pandoc?

Tags: latex, sublimetext3, markdown, pandoc

I am having trouble compile markdown files with latex equation using Pandoc. The code is the following:

```
+ Regression Specification: 
+ $y_{gpt} = \alpha+\beta_1 * Parallel+ \gamma * Prov_p+ \delta * 
  Year_t+\epsiolon_{gpt}$
```

I get an undefined control sequence error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in `\epsilon`, this works:

```
+ Regression Specification: 
+ $y_{gpt} = \alpha+\beta_1 * Parallel+ \gamma * Prov_p+ \delta * 
  Year_t+\epsilon_{gpt}$
```

(btw. not sure why you have those plus sings at the beginning: they produce an ordered list which seems odd in this context.)